# Trouble using Predicate Builder in Foreach Loop

Tags: c#

I am required to create multiple `And` conditions using the Predicate Builder  in a foreach loop but the predicate is taking the latest `And` condition. Basically, the predicate should contain the list of `And` conditions as the `reportProfileid`'s contains the list

```
 var cpaclassids = FetchProductTypes(ids); 
 var temp = cpaclassids;

 var query = (from x in partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery()
                  join y in partRepository.GetPartsQuery() on x.PartId equals y.Id
                  join z in partProductTypeReposiotry.GetPartProductTypesQuery() on x.PartId equals z.PartId
                  where y.IsSkipped == 0 && (y.IsDisabled != "Y" || y.IsDisabled == null) && z.CreatedDate == x.CreatedDate
                  && x.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate)
                  select x).Cast<PartJoinTable>();

 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);

 foreach (var item in reportProfilesids)
 {
    predicate = predicate.And(z => temp.Contains(z.ProductTypeId.ToString()));
 }

var lst1 = query.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: you can use the `temp` by simply call it as `var lst1 = query.Where(w=>temp.contains(w.ProductTypeId)).Distinct().ToList()` to get the related data instead of using the `foreach` as you are not using the `item` from it.

Comment: var reportProfilesids = GetReportProfileslists(selectedReportProfile).Where(y => cpaselections.Contains(y.Text)).Select(a => new { a.Value, a.Type }).ToList();